# Getting past "infinite expression 1/0 encountered"

Tags: functions

The following function

```
Angel[startingBankroll_, investmentSize_, successProbability_, investmentsToMake_, targetReturnMultiple_, numberOfSimulations_] := 
   With[{
    simulationData = NestList[If[(RandomReal[] < successProbability) && #  >= 0, (targetReturnMultiple) (investmentSize), Max[#-investmentSize, 0]] &, 
                                                                startingBankroll, 
                                                                      investmentsToMake],
    runs = Table[simulationData, {r, numberOfSimulations}],
         finalBankrolls = Map[Last, runs],
      frequencyOfBust = Count[finalBankrolls, u_ /; u <= 0] / Length[finalBankrolls],
      frequencyOfOutsizedReturn = Count[finalBankrolls, u_ /; u  >Max[(startingBankroll - (investmentsToMake)(investmentSize)),0]] / Length[finalBankrolls]
    },
    runs]
Angel[100000, 5000, 0.05, 10, 1000, 10]
```

yields an "infinite expression 1/0 encountered" error:

> [image]

How does one get past this?

Comment: Presumably this is due to `Length[finalBankrolls]` being 0.

Answer (score 4):

Since this question is a [follow-up](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198965/can-mathematica-plot-this-financial-simulation/198977#198977), this answer will, for the most part, depend on my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198965/can-mathematica-plot-this-financial-simulation/198977#198977) there.

Before getting down to the details of the answer, I would like to comment on a few issues with the code in this question.

### `With` does *not* 'do' recursive definitions

Namely, one issue is that `With` does *not* support the kind of *sequential assignments* used as a first argument. What that means is that evaluating something like

```
With[{x = 3, y = x^2},
  3 y + 1
 ]
```

does *not* return `28` as it would have been probably expected, but `3 x^2 + 1` (assuming of course that `x` is a symbol that does not evaluate to anything else eg some numeric value, during the course of evaluation).

As it is the case that another answer to this question links to a *really* useful post about the different scope constructs in Mathematica, I'd like to provide a link to an answer that actually implements a [*recursive* version](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10432/how-to-avoid-nested-with) of `With` in the sense expounded above.

Since this is a slightly more involved avenue to travel down to, I would like to propose a way to solve the problem in the question without having to actually implement such *exotic* solutions (exotic in the sense that the answer can be derived with simpler means not in the sense that the linked answer is useless or irrelevant, *far from it*).

### `Set` and `SetDelayed` have different effects

Another issue with the code in the question is related to the final two attempts at *recursive* definitions in `With`. The assignment made to `simulationData` uses `Set` *not* `SetDelayed`. This means that once the assignment is made, the value of `simulationData` does not change in subsequent evaluations. This is not a problem *per se* but it creates a problem for the flow of the simulation because when the `runs` are calculated (outside the first argument of `With` this time) they will *not* contain *different* random sequences but the *same* random sequence that was evaluated the *first time* `With` was evaluated. I don't think this is the intended behavior of the code segment.

### Minor conceptual and practical issues

Related to `simulationData` is a conceptual issue; the way `NestList` iterates the nested results, upon success it returns *just* the prize of the investment while upon failure it returns a figure that is conceptually (probably) expected to be the result from continuously investing (either a positive number or zero) but in actual fact   that is not the case. Upon success, the result that gets passed to the next iteration of `NestList` is simply the *increment* in available funds instead of the sum of the available funds augmented by any possible gains from investing; therefore `simulationData` does not record '*wealth*' (stock) but '*income*' (flow), so to speak.

Finally, the assignment to `finalBankrolls` is redundant; it is possible to obtain the same effect when needed with less effort. This wouldn't have been a serious problem with the code, had the problem with the recursive definitions not been an issue to begin with.

---

### Proposed solution

The proposed solution extends my answer in the previous question in such a way as to obtain the required statistics ie. `frequencyOfBust` and `frequencyOfOutsizedReturn`.

There are minor changes needed inside the code of `simulation` and the addition of a function that performs the desired calculations.

1. The first line in the `Module` of `simulation` should read

   ```
   {distribution, repetitions, observations} = {args};
   ```

   This line is prepended in order to make the arguments of `randomSequence` available in the rest of the code.
2. `label` (just before `legend`) should now read

   ```
   label = Row[Riffle[Thread[header -> {args}], ", "]]
   ```
3. The last line of `simulation` should be modified to

   ```
   Join[{Legended[ListLinePlot[series, Apply[Sequence][opts]], Placed[legend, Below]]}, 
     collectStats[series, capital, repetitions, observations]]
   ```

   where `collectStats` is the new function that will perform the required calculations.

Following is the implementation of `collectStats`:

```
collectStats[randomMatrix_, args___] := Module[{capital, repetitions, observations, folder, combined, 
  bustFreq, xtrmRets, onBust, opts, label},

  (* retrieve relevant args *)
  {capital, repetitions, observations} = {args};

  (* frequency of bust and 'extreme' returns *)
  folder = With[{sum = #1 + #2}, If[sum >= 0, sum, -Infinity]] &;
  combined = With[{diff = #, maxDiff = Max[#]},
    {Fold[folder, capital, diff], {maxDiff, Count[#, maxDiff]}}
   ] & /@ Differences[randomMatrix, {0, 1}];

  (* bustFreq is a list with elements -Infinity or some positive figure *)
  (* xtrmRets is a list with elements {some figure, its frequency} *)
  {bustFreq, xtrmRets} = combined // Transpose;

  (* NumericQ[Infinity] -> False allows us to distinguish between normal occasions and busts *)

  onBust = If[NumericQ[#1], #2, {Null, 0.}] &;

  {
    label = StringTemplate["Absolute frequency of busts in `1` samples"];
    opts = {ChartLabels -> (Style[#, FontSize -> Large] & /@ {"normal", "bust"}), 
      PlotLabel -> label[repetitions], ImageSize -> Medium, ChartStyle -> 96};
    Framed@PieChart[{#[True], #[False]}, 
      Apply[Sequence][opts]] &@(Length /@     GroupBy[bustFreq, NumericQ]),

    label = StringTemplate["Absolute frequency of max returns in `1` observations\n(in normal situations)"];
    opts = {ChartLabels -> Range[repetitions], Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Medium, 
      PlotLabel -> label[observations], ChartStyle -> 24};
    BarChart[#2, Apply[Sequence][opts]] & @@ Transpose[Map[Apply[onBust], combined]],

    Iconize[combined, "data"]
   }

]
```

Evaluating

```
simulation[randomSequence[UniformDistribution[], 15, 10^3],
  10^4, 5 10^3, 10^3, 0.915] // Most /* (Riffle[#, Null] &) /* Row
```

returns

> [image: Blockquote]

Answer (score 3):

So you tried to refer to the local variables: `With[{x = 1, y = x}, ...]` which will not achieve what you want. I would recommend using the `Module` (See [this post by Leonid Shifrin](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs) for a good overview of localizing mechanism in Mathematica). Here is the code:

```
Angel[startingBankroll_, investmentSize_, successProbability_, 
    investmentsToMake_, targetReturnMultiple_, numberOfSimulations_] := 
  Module[{simulationData, runs, finalBankrolls, frequencyOfBust, frequencyOfOutsizedReturn},
    simulationData := NestList[
        If[(RandomReal[] < successProbability) && # >= 0, 
           (targetReturnMultiple) (investmentSize), 
           Max[# - investmentSize, 0]
        ] &, startingBankroll, investmentsToMake]; 
    runs = Table[simulationData, {r, numberOfSimulations}];
    finalBankrolls = Map[Last, runs];
    frequencyOfBust = Count[finalBankrolls, u_ /; u <= 0]/Length[finalBankrolls];
    frequencyOfOutsizedReturn = Count[finalBankrolls, 
         u_ /; u > Max[(startingBankroll - (investmentsToMake) (investmentSize)), 0]
      ] / Length[finalBankrolls];
    runs
];
```

Also, another point is that if you want different simulation results at each run, `simulationData` should be defined by `SetDelayed`, i.e., `:=`.

Comment: This worked the first time I ran it, but subsequent runs cause the 1/0 errors to come back.  I tried changing all remaining `=` to `:=` to see if that would fix it but it didn't. I also tried changing the final `runs` at the end to i.e. `frequencyOfOutsizedReturn` and the same errors occurred. Very strange.

Comment: Do you mind posting your full code? I tried on my machine with 12.0 and it works fine.